# Have problems with SQLite in Python

Tags: python, sqlite, pyqt

I want to add into my SQLite table a list of values. To be more accurate, I want to add it in Stock column. But I have some problems when running my app. Here is my database before app running.

[image]

And when I try running my programm, I got wrong column data. Here is my code

```
def count(ui):
    i = []
    z = 0
    v = 0
    if ui.comboBox.currentText() == '50НР4':
        cur.execute("""SELECT Part, Stock FROM Details WHERE Pumps = '50НР4' OR Pumps = '50НР4/6'""")
    elif ui.comboBox.currentText() == '50НР6.3':
        cur.execute("""SELECT Part, Stock FROM Details WHERE Pumps = '50НР6' OR Pumps = '50НР4/6'""")
    for row, form in enumerate(cur):
        i.append(form[1])
    for element in i:
        i[z] -= 1
        z += 1

    if ui.comboBox.currentText() == '50НР4':
        z = 0
        for elem in i:
            cur.execute("""UPDATE Details SET Stock = (?) WHERE Pumps = '50НР4' OR Pumps = '50НР4/6' AND ROWID = (?)""",
                        [i[z], v])
            v += 1
            z += 1
    elif ui.comboBox.currentText() == '50НР6.3':
        z = 0
        for elem in i:
            cur.execute("""UPDATE Details SET Stock = (?) WHERE Pumps = '50НР6' OR Pumps = '50НР4/6' AND ROWID = (?)""",
                        [i[z], v])
            v += 1
            z += 1
    elif ui.comboBox.currentText() == '50НР4' or ui.comboBox.currentText() == '50НР6':
        z = 0
        for elem in i:
            cur.execute("""UPDATE Details SET Stock = (?) WHERE Pumps = '50НР4/6' AND ROWID = (?)""", [i[z], v])
            v += 1
            z += 1
    print(i)
    con.commit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the values of rows, just let the database do it for you internally:

```
def count(ui):
    if ui.comboBox.currentText() == '50НР4':
        condition = "Pumps = '50НР4' OR Pumps = '50НР4/6'"
    elif ui.comboBox.currentText() == '50НР6.3':
        condition = "Pumps = '50НР6' OR Pumps = '50НР4/6'"
    else:
        condition = "Pumps = '50НР4/6'"
    cur.execute("""UPDATE Details SET Stock = Stock - 1 WHERE %s""" % condition)
    con.commit()
```

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot... I am new in python, and this is my first application written on it. And i was thinking on this task for about 3 days. Thaks, this helped me!